# I want to download and upload pictures on dropbox and use it as a datastore. Is that possible?

Tags: android, cloud, dropbox, dropbox-api, datastore

I am developing an app for Android. I need a datastore so user can upload and download images via the app. It's possible to let every user upload images via Dropbox-android-api on my dropbox storage/account? So what I want is to let user upload images on my Dropbox account without having a dropbox account of them self. Is that possible? The example apps of the dropbox-android-api uses user-registration to upload files. So they need to have a DropBox-Account. I only want to use it as a datastore.

If this is not possible, what is the best way to store images in the cloud and which are the best provider for that with less costs.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox API is intended to be used by apps to the extent that each user interacts with their own account, but it would be technically possible to interact with one predefined account. The basic idea would be to embed an access token authorized for your account in the app, and the always re-use that. This isn't recommended though, and is generally not a good idea, due to some technical and security issues. (For example, anyone could extract the access token and do whatever they want to the contents of the account.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it's better to use something like parse.com.